# clang: error: unknown argument: '-stdc++'

Tags: ios8, xcode6

[image]

I am getting error as

clang: error: unknown argument: '-stdc++'

what causes this error?.How to solve this?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

That is the option for the language specifier.  You are missing the = sign and the language specifier that comes after it will depend on the version of the language you are compiling for.
Example, targeting C++11

```
-std=c++11
```

The man page for your tool chain should document the available supported languages.